# Getting std::valarray to (google/quick) bench properly

Tags: c++, valarray, google-benchmark

I'm trying to compare the performance of using `std::valarray` vs. `std::vector`/`std::transform` operations using Google Bench. I'm using QuickBench.

My code (for QuickBench) is

```
#include <random>

class RG {
public:
    double operator()() noexcept { return dis(gen); } 
private:
    std::mt19937 gen {std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis {0.0, 100.0};
};

static RG rg {};

static constexpr auto N = 1000;

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static void Vector(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<double> v1, v2;
    v1.reserve(N); v2.reserve(N);
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(v1),N,rg);
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(v2),N,rg);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::vector<double> v3; v3.reserve(N);
        std::transform(cbegin(v1), cend(v1), cbegin(v2), back_inserter(v3),
            [](auto d1, auto d2) noexcept { return 0.5*d1+1.5*d2;});
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(v3);
    }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(Vector);

#include <valarray>

static void ValArray(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::valarray<double> v1{N}, v2{N};
    std::generate(begin(v1),end(v1),rg);
    std::generate(begin(v2),end(v2),rg);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::valarray<double> v3{};
        v3=0.5*v1+1.5*v2;
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(v3);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(ValArray);
```

[QuickBench link](https://quick-bench.com/q/7cTTVIBJ0FYwhuD69gO4ItXqdFo)
Quickbench says the `std::valarray` is 72 times faster then `std::vector`. That can't be right, right?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem with `std::vector` is that it either forces a zero-initialization on you (resize) or lots of branches constantly checking if new allocation is needed (reserve + back_inserter). `unique_ptr` gives similar perf to `valarray`:  https://quick-bench.com/q/-aLzQp5kI0AfjU4rj7teRA_Pk5g

Comment: Here's one with 500,000 elements and `par_unseq` versions: https://quick-bench.com/q/hF3uylCLK5lMWnj0hZLVTjN23j4

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili thanks. I just wanted to know if valarray was any performant. I never see it used in any code. An I found some post about it, calling it "broken". (In my experience part of it were actually broken [and just recently fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/commit/0e7b5d2509b96f7880bf69417264328df0d53c58#diff-7adde92f40f18f0ab2ae0e1f5828ea180f7a0ff83acd140990d3a65b818d6339). But benching it I found it performs pretty good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 36:

```cpp
std::valarray<double> v1{N}, v2{N};
```

This creates two one-element `valarray`-s, that is, each containing a single element whose value is `N=1000`. This is because the list-initialization syntax, `{}`, uses the constructor taking `std::initializer_list`:

```cpp
valarray(std::initializer_list<T> il);
```

which constructs a `valarray` with the contents of that list, as opposed to the intended one:

```cpp
explicit valarray(std::size_t count);
```

that would construct a `valarray` of `count` elements.

You need to change that line to:

```cpp
std::valarray<double> v1(N), v2(N);
```